# viewflipper not works on 4.0

Tags: android, android-layout

i have developed an application that works fine on android 2.1 version but when i launch it on android 4.0 version it does not run and throws the stack trace like this:

```
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:524)
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:499)
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1937)
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:664)
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:542)
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:315)
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.deedatech.AnimalsNameForKids.AnimalsNameForKidsActivity.onCreate(AnimalsNameForKidsActivity.java:85)
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-26 19:45:10.961: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native   Method)
```

i just dont understand why this happens because the same program runs perfect on android 2.1 version but throws `outOfMemoryError` on 4.0 version. please help if u have some idea..

Answer (score 0):

If you are decoding a Bitmap from the UI thread, there is a risk to get the outOfMemoryError. Try to change your decode stream to an asynTask.

Comment: but if this is the problem then why it doesnot shows it on android 2.1 version. pls help me out.

Comment: the internal implementation of the android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate native method has changed, maybe on 4.0 it needs more memory size.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what Anis said, decoding yor Bitmap on a different thread will not help you avoid an Out Of Memory (OOM) Error, you're still loading exactly the same amount of data into your application.

You need to either reduce the size of the image you are loading or downsample it so you aren't loading in all of the data, for more information on this take a look at [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

Comment: but if this is the problem then why it doesnot shows it on android 2.1 version. pls help me out.

Comment: Because the OS is different so the amount of free memory may not be the same. Also the devices may be different.